# Apply coordinates after scene restart in hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have the following setup right now:

- "Startup" scene which initializes all managers (spatial mapping, cursors, camera, ...)
- "Main" scene with animations and one object which moves around

Once the users interacts with the program the scene restarts at some point, then the following should happen:

- Object's coordinates get stored (E.g. DontDestroyOnLoad() on a "storage object". I need to destroy the object since it needs to reset itself on scene restart)
- Scene restarts
- Object gets recreated with stored coordinates

Code:

```
DataPositionStorer positionStorer = new GameObject("DataPositionStorer").AddComponent<DataPositionStorer>();
DontDestroyOnLoad(positionStorer.gameObject);
// dataPoints is the specific object I need to keep the coordinates of
positionStorer.Position = dataPoints.transform.position;
positionStorer.Rotation = dataPoints.transform.rotation;
positionStorer.Zoom = dataPoints.transform.localScale;

// Reload current scene ("Main")
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

And in the startup method of the object:

```
DataPositionStorer positionStorer = FindObjectOfType<DataPositionStorer>();
if (positionStorer!= null)
{
    dataPoints.transform.position = positionStorer.Position;
    dataPoints.transform.localRotation = positionStorer.Rotation;
    dataPoints.transform.localScale = positionStorer.Zoom;
}
```

This setup works in the unity player but once I run it in the hololens emulator / on a hololens the position afterwards isn't correct anymore.

Can somebody help me resolve this problem on the emulator / hololens?

Comment: Quite a few things that could cause wrong positioning. Are you rescanning the environment? Without a WorldAnchor somewhere in your process, your going to have trouble with coordinates being different.

Comment: I agree, for this approach to work you really need to use world anchors and attach them to the objects that you want to persist between scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the two guys commenting I've found a solution:

- Load the WorldAnchorManager Script in the Setup scene and make it DontDestroyOnLoad
- Attach a World Anchor before the scene restarts
- Load the World Anchor after the scene restarted

This however only works on the emulator / HoloLens itself. In the Unity Editor World Anchors don't work! So just copy paste the coordinates over like I did in my initial post.